# Overriding PreMessageLoop, when should I call CAtlServiceModuleT::PreMessageLoop

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, atl

I've got a service project in Visual Studio 2005 that was converted to a Visual Studio 2010 project. And I've noticed a problem with the PreMessageLoop function, which looks like this:

```
HRESULT CMyModule::PreMessageLoop (int nShowCmd)
{
    HRESULT result = CAtlServiceModuleT<CMyModule,100>::PreMessageLoop(nShowCmd);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == result)
    {
        ComplicatedInitialization();
        _AtlModule.SetServiceStatus (SERVICE_START_PENDING);
        MoreComplicatedInitialization();
        _AtlModule.SetServiceStatus (SERVICE_START_PENDING);
        StillMoreComplicatedInitialization();
        _AtlModule.SetServiceStatus (SERVICE_START_PENDING);
        EvenMoreComplicatedInitialization();
    }
    return result;
}
```

This works great in Visual C++ 2005: The Run function calls my PreMessageLoop, which calls the base-class PreMessageLoop. The complicated initialization happens when the service is in SERVICE_START_PENDING. When my PreMessageLoop returns, Run calls SetServiceStatus(SERVICE_RUNNING).

Visual C++ 2010 is different: the base-class PreMessageLoop calls SetServiceStatus(SERVICE_RUNNING). The complicated initialization happens when the service is in SERVICE_RUNNING state, which is not good (because the service looks like it is running when it is in fact still initializing).

Can I simply move the base-class PreMessageLoop call to the bottom of my PreMessageLoop call? Or is it more complicated than a simple move?

## Followup

It appears that a service can go from the SERVICE_RUNNING state back to the SERVICE_START_PENDING state. Is that wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, "if (ERROR_SUCCESS == result)" is something not quite correct, as you should be checking result against HRESULT values, that is against `S_OK`, `S_FALSE`, or using `SUCCEEDED` sort of macros.

Base `PreMessageLoop` is registering COM class objects, if your complicated initialization is not using COM instanatiation you are free to move your stuff above `__super::PreMessageLoop` call.

Comment: Some of the complicated initialization is calling SQL Server Compact or SQL Server or Oracle to initialize a whole bunch of internal objects. The SQL Server calls go through COM. Would that be "using COM instanatiation"?

Comment: Well, in case you need internal COM object instantiation and this simple solution does not work for you, you can still do the following: override the entire PreMessageLoop by copying it from ancestor and don't call ancestor anymore. Comment out the early SetServiceStatus calls and only notify running state when you are done with initialization. This way it will be the same way you had it with 2005/2008 ATL.

Answer (score 0):

The COM Initialization codes in PreMessageLoop are causing the Error 1053.

Solution 1: Disable the COM Support.

```
#define _ATL_NO_COM_SUPPORT
```

in "stdafx.h" before all ATL related includes.

Solution 2: Override the "PreMessageLoop" and strip it from the COM Initialization codes.

```
HRESULT PreMessageLoop(_In_ int nShowCmd) throw()
{
    if (m_bService)
    {
        // Make sure that service was not stoped during initialization
        if (::InterlockedCompareExchange(&m_status.dwCurrentState, SERVICE_RUNNING, SERVICE_START_PENDING) == SERVICE_START_PENDING)
        {
            LogEvent(_T("Service started/resumed"));
            ::SetServiceStatus(m_hServiceStatus, &m_status);
        }
    }

    // Start the tread(s)
    _worker = new CWorkerThread();

    return S_OK;
}
```